# THREE.js GLTFLoader does not works on loading the 3D model

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, 3d, gltf

Hi I am facing a problem on cannot display the 3D model THREE.js GLTFLoader(), the following is my script:

Here is the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>hey</li>
            <li>heysda</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    
    <div class="scene"></div>
    <script src="./three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./GLTFLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

here is the js file:

```
//Variables for setup

let container;
let camera;
let renderer;
let scene;
let house;

function init() {
  container = document.querySelector(".scene");

  //Create scene
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const fov = 35;
  const aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight;
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 1000;

  //Camera setup
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.set(0, 0, 100);

  const ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040, 2);
  scene.add(ambient);

  const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 2);
  light.position.set(50, 50, 100);
  scene.add(light);
  //Renderer
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });
  renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);

  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  //Load Model
  let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
  loader.load("./house/scene.gltf", function(gltf) {
    scene.add(gltf.scene);
    house = gltf.scene.children[0];
    animate();
  });
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  house.rotation.z += 0.005;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

init();

function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
}

window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize);
```

I ran the code on notepad++ and chrome browser, but it turned out blank screen without showing my 3D model.

Anyone knows the solution? thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mind sharing the glTF asset in your thread?

Comment: Hi @Mugen87, here is the GITF files https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1o7ri5dwk7VjSBoBj5nBfv6mnkmzt6kSS?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way how you work with `container` is problematic since `clientHeight` is zero when you access it to compute the aspect ratio. I suggest you start with using `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` at the beginning.

Besides, there are two minor issues with your model. The model has an extreme scale so you won't see it with your current camera position. You are way too close. Besides, the model has an offset so it's recommended to center it. Try it with this code:

```js
//Variables for setup

let camera;
let renderer;
let scene;
let house;

init();

function init() {

    //Create scene
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    const fov = 60;
    const aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    const near = 0.1;
    const far = 1000;

    //Camera setup
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( fov, aspect, near, far );
    camera.position.set( 0, 0, 5 );

    const ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff, 0.4 );
    scene.add( ambient );

    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 );
    light.position.set( 0, 0, 10 );
    scene.add( light );

    //Renderer
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    //Load Model
    const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    loader.load( './house/scene.gltf', function ( gltf ) {

        house = gltf.scene;

        // scale model down

        house.scale.setScalar( 0.001 );

        // center it

        const box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( house );
        const center = box.getCenter( new THREE.Vector3() );

        house.position.x += ( house.position.x - center.x );
        house.position.y += ( house.position.y - center.y );
        house.position.z += ( house.position.z - center.z );

        scene.add( house );

        animate();

    } );

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}

function onWindowResize() {

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

}

window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );
```

Comment: I already tried your script but still no luck... my 3D model still can't be displayed, may I know if it is because I am using localhost to run the html file? should I using port server like 127.0.0.1:8000 to run it?

Comment: This is the screenshot of the result: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KbZP9M8pP16vtYJS1vpp2jrZdc9zzUCh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please remove `<div class="scene"></div>` and all other markup and CSS except for the JavaScript imports and then try again.

Comment: Using localhost is absolutely fine. It's just important that you host the application on a web server.

Comment: Here is the above code as a live example: https://zinc-bouncy-gauge.glitch.me

Comment: Finally I did it! Thanks. I think my problem was I just dragged and dropped the html file onto browser, now I hosted the file on xampp, so problem solved! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Mind to if I ask you another question? How to change the background like I want to put a motion background, something like this https://i1.wp.com/codemyui.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/pure-css-snow-animation.gif?fit=880%2C440&ssl=1, does it possible to do that?

Comment: One last question, how should I control the 3D model like rotating it 360 degree? sorry if I asking too much

Comment: Sorry but it's best if you open a thread for each question when using stackoverflow. Or consider to use the [three.js forum](https://discourse.threejs.org/) if you want to ask multiple question in a single topic.